# T-SQL Merge pairs of rows with similar datetime

Tags: t-sql, merge

Is it possible to merge pairs of rows with similar (<500 ms) datetime values, and left other rows as it is ?

I have following table of events:

```
ID    DateTime                  FileName  Event
=================================================
001   2011-04-04 12:30:15.000   File_A    Deleted
002   2011-04-04 15:30:37.000   File_A    Created
003   2011-04-05 08:30:25.000   File_A    Deleted
004   2011-04-05 08:30:25.050   File_A    Created
```

If I have pair of Deleted and Created events inside timespan of 500 ms, query should merge these two rows, and put Event as "Modified".

Result should be:

```
DateTime                  FileName  Event
============================================
2011-04-04 12:30:15.000   File_A    Deleted
2011-04-04 15:30:37.000   File_A    Created
2011-04-05 08:30:25.000   File_A    Modified
```

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT t1.DateTime, t1.FileName, 'Modified' as Event
FROM Table t1
JOIN Table t2 ON DATEDIFF(millisecond, t1.DateTime, t2.DateTime) < 500
              AND t1.Event = 'Deleted' AND t2.Event = 'Created'
UNION ALL
SELECT t3.DateTime, t3.FileName, t3.Event
FROM Table t3 
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 
                 FROM Table t4
                 JOIN Table t5 ON DATEDIFF(millisecond, t4.DateTime, t5.DateTime) < 500
                               AND t4.Event = 'Deleted' AND t5.Event = 'Created' 
                               AND t3.ID IN (t4.ID, t5.ID)
)
```

...okay, there has to be a better way to pull the non-merged results back. But this *should* work?

Comment: It works perfectly for Modified (merged), but just wandering how to find out rows which do not have "neighbour" and UNION SELECT with your query...

Comment: @buggy08 Yeah, I added that in. It *should* work, theoretically, but it's ugly, imo.

Comment: Whoops. Missed the SELECT on the second part, /doh

Comment: No problem :-) It works perfectly as it is. I'll need it for some temporary analysis, so thanks for the help...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select cast(DATEPART(hour, DateColumn) as varchar(2)) + ':' + cast(DATEPART(minute, DateColumn) as varchar(2)) + ':' + cast(DATEPART(second, DateColumn) as varchar(2)) as DateTime,
max(filename) as FileName, Max(event) as event
from table
group by 
cast(DATEPART(hour, DateColumn) as varchar(2)) + ':' + cast(DATEPART(minute, DateColumn) as varchar(2)) + ':' + cast(DATEPART(second, DateColumn) as varchar(2)) as DateTime
```

Comment: Basicaly elegant idea, but datetime values might be for example: 08:30:14.990 and 08:30:15:010, so by casting seconds as you proposed would not find it as pair, although they are. Thanks anyway.